# Ubuntu 15.10 startup loops on cryptswap pass phrase request

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, encryption, 15.10, boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14242642/

For this PC I installed Ubuntu 15.10, with an encrypted home folder, on a GPT drive, followed by Windows 7 in UEFI mode. I then repaired GRUB 2 with boot-repair on a live disk, since GRUB 2 would no longer display and the PC would boot Windows directly. While I am now able to select Ubuntu using GRUB 2, the process seems to halt on a screen that displays the following message: "Please enter passphrase for disk [disk_name] (cryptswap1) on none!"

When I use Ubuntu's recovery mode, the file system status is read-only. Updating GRUB changes the file system's status to read/write and from there I can boot normally.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with initram

Comment: I have read the initramfs wiki page, but I have very little experience with Linux. Is the pass phrase at startup only necessary when root is encrypted? I have access to the encrypted partition even when I do not enter it. Seems like a reinstall might be the simplest solution?

Comment: If the error is initram related this might help: https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/fix-a-failed-initramfs-update-do-it-before-you-reboot/

Comment: Thanks for the link. None of the fixes seem to address my problem directly, but I'll try and tinker it a little. Most likely, I'll do a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a bug, as I have had a similar situation, "fixed" though by purposely mistyping the passphrase (password of main account). Also how long did you have it installed before prompt appeared? EDIT: Oh looks like you already said you encrypted home, oops. :P

EDIT2: Happened after a while using my PC after recovering my partitions with testdisk, after deleting my partition table on accident, lol. Did you also check though that your checksums for your copy of Ubuntu matches the website's?

EDIT3: It. Came. Back. :( For once that is, but still strange.

Comment: I believe there was one checksum entry that was different.  I eventually reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 without encrypting the home folder.

Comment: Now it bugs me once in a while, nearly every day. :( I think there might be a way to fix it though, might involve removing and creating a new swap partition.